# git commiting new files even if not added and committed

Tags: git

I added a new file to my master repository and edited a few, I only committed the ones I edited.  Now the commit history on repo I pushed to is showing file changes in the edited files I added AND the new one I I created even though I did not add the new one.

TLDR: I did not add a newly created file to a commit but it was included in push anyway.

Comment: What commands did you run when doing the add?

Comment: Could you try to do the same again and post the exact sequence of commands you used?

Comment: Did you include an `-a` flag on your `git commit`? That's effectively the same as a `git add .; git commit`

Comment: @Gareth - No, `-a` add modifications to already tracked files only. Not untracked files.

Comment: ah yes, sorry. `commit -a` is like `add -u`, not `add .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did in fact add it. You probably typed the wrong thing and didn't realize it (e.g. `git add -A` instead of `git add -u`, the `-A` picks up new files whereas `-u` only picks up modified ones). If you want to avoid issues like this in the future, you might want to get in the habit of using `git diff --cached` before committing to verify what you're about to commit, or using `git show` after committing to review your commit before you push it anywhere. Also note that the editor for the commit message will show a summary of the files included in the commit, so you can check that and make sure it's not including files you didn't intend to commit.

Comment: 'git add -a' is giving me unknown swithc error do you mean 'git add -u'

Comment: @alex_borsody: Err yes, yes I do. I'll fix my answer.